# Scrapy parse webpage, extract results pages, and download images

Tags: python, image, search, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a web crawler in python using Beautiful Soup and requests to scrape images for a project, but the speed is slow. I heard Scrapy is much faster so I've installed it and read a load of tutorials but I can't figure out how to implement the crawler in the `parse` function of the spider script.

If I provide the link to the first page of search results, it should:

1. Find the number of pages in search results, by analyzing the `<a>` tag for a specific class
2. Get links based on the `<a>` tag for a specific class, and
3. Download the images from these links based on a specific `'id'`

I've updated the items and settings scripts as shown down below. Any help you can give me is massively appreciated.

items.py

```
import scrapy

class SampleItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    images = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'scrapy.pipeline.images.FilesPipeline': 1
}
FILES_STORE = '/Documents/scraped_images/'
```

Comment: scrapy uses threading to download many pages/files at the same time - but `requests` has also special versions which use `threading`, `multiprocessing` or `asyncio` to run many pages/files at the same time. And it makes it faster.

Comment: you set absolute path `'/Documents/scraped_images/'` - do you have this folder on disk ? It is not relative but absolut path.

Comment: to download images you have to scrape urls to images and put them in `SampleItem.images`. It doesn't works automatically. It doesn't search automatically urls to images and it doesn't download automatically images - you have to manually put urls in  `SampleItem.images`

Comment: if you use `FilesPipelines` then you have to use `file_urls` instead of `image_urls`. If you use `ImagesPipelines` then you need `image_urls` - but it will convert images to JPG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is minimal example which downloads images from main page on http://books.toscrape.com/

You can put all code in one file and run `python script.py` without creating project.

You have to find images on HTML and add to `Item` (or yield as dictionary). It doesn't do this automatically.

If you use `FilesPipeline` then you have to use `file_urls` instead of `images_urls`.

Path which you use in `FILES_STORE` has to exists. It will not create it - and if folder doesn't exist then it doesn't download files. But it will create automatically subfolder `full/` in `FILES_STORE` to keep original images.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    #allowed_domains = []

    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        # download files (not only images, but without converting to JPG)
        for url in response.css('img::attr(src)').extract():
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield {'file_urls': [url]}


# --- run it in the same file ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    #'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    #'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #

    # used standard FilesPipeline (download to FILES_STORE/full)
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1},  

    # this folder has to exist before downloading
    'FILES_STORE': '.',                   
})

c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

---

**EDIT:** I add `RenameFilesPipeline` which renames path to move files to subfolder with current date and time. You don't have to create subfolder - it will create it automatically.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
import datetime
import time

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    #allowed_domains = []

    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        # download files (not only images, but without converting to JPG)
        for url in response.css('img::attr(src)').extract():
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield {'file_urls': [url]}


class RenameFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    '''Pipeline to change file names - to add folder name with date and time'''

    # create it only once - when Scrapy creates instance of RenameFilesPipeline
    pattern = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('images/%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S/{}')

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        '''Changing file name - adding folder name with date and time'''

        name = request.url.split('/')[-1]
        filename = self.pattern.format(name)
        print('filename:', filename)

        return filename

# --- run it in the same file ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    # used standard FilesPipeline (download to FILES_STORE/full)
    #'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1},  

    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.RenameFilesPipeline': 1},  

    # this folder has to exist before downloading
    'FILES_STORE': '.',                   
})

c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Is there a situation where you would want a full project for a web scraper?

Comment: Your code works, but how can I automatically rename the downloaded images and choose the name of the folder it creates to store the images?

Comment: if you wnat to put in different folder then use different `FILES_STORE` . If you want to rename and/or put different files to different folders then you have to write own `FilesPipeline` - see example `RenameImagePipeline` in my [template](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/scrapy/__template__/python%20-%20scrapy.py) on GitHub. See also [rename-csv-and-image-folder-using-datetime](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/scrapy/rename-csv-and-image-folder-using-datetime/main.py)